# Non-Hamiltonian $k$-connected $k$-regular graphs ($k>3$)?

Tags: graph-theory

The [Petersen graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PetersenGraph.html) provides us with an example of an non-Hamiltonian 3-connected 3-regular graph. Are any 4-connected 4-regular graphs known to be non-Hamiltonian? What about generic $k$-connected $k$-regular graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0095895673800061/1-s2.0-S0095895673800061-main.pdf?_tid=b3cc7cd8-d2c2-11e3-b8db-00000aacb361&acdnat=1399122123_c25e64a6fddf73fba84d8edbf7923de8) (Regular n-Valent n-Connected NonHamiltonian Non-n-Edge-Colorable Graphs by G. H. J. Meredith) the answer is yes (by construction) for $k=4$ and $k \ge 8$ but the other cases are not shown there. You can see a nice picture of the construction (which goes via the Petersen graph) for $k=4$ on page 5.