# Find a minimum 2-connected 5-regular non-Hamiltonian graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity, hamiltonicity

**Inspired by the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779239/non-hamiltonian-k-connected-k-regular-graphs-k3).**

According to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895673800061), there are $k$-connected $k$-regular non-Hamiltonian graphs for $k=4$ and $k \ge 8$ but the other cases are not shown there.

Now I need to **construct a 2-connected 5-regular non-Hamiltonian graph.**

Let $P$ denote the Petersen graph, and let $P^{\prime}$ denote the graph obtained from $P$ by replacing one vertex $v$ of $P$ by the complete graph $K_3$ and making each vertex of the $K_3$ adjacent to a distinct neighbor of $v$.  Hilbig proved the following theorem:

**Theorem 1.** (See Hilbig [1].) If $G$ is a 2-connected $k$-regular graph on at most $3 k+3$ vertices and $G \notin\left\{P, P^{\prime}\right\}$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Therefore, the graph I desire should have at least 20 vertices.
I searched in [house of graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/), but I couldn't find a graph that meets the criteria.

**Edits:** I have constructed one (with 32 vertices). Perhaps it would be more meaningful to ask for **a minimum graph** (i.e, with minimum number of vertices） that satisfies the above properties.

[image]

> The graph above is not a Hamiltonian graph, as can be inferred from
> the proposition below. (Note that if we remove the two vertices on the left
> and right sides of the graph, we will see that the remaining subgraph
> has five connected components.)
>
> **Proposition 1.** If $G$ is a graph containing a set $S \subset V(G)$ such that $G-S$ has more than $|S|$ components, then $G$ is not
> Hamiltonian.
>
> **Proof.** Any Hamiltonian cycle must use a distinct vertex of $S$ each time it leaves $S$, so if $G$ is Hamiltonian, $G-S$ has at most
> $|S|$ components.

[1] F. Hilbig, Kantenstrukturen in nichthamiltonschen Graphen, Ph.D. thesis, Technische Universität Berlin, 1986.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the $32$-vertex example, deleting the leftmost and rightmost vertices leaves $5$ components, but it would be enough if we were left with $3$ components. We can do that instead, getting a $20$-vertex example.

Let $x$ and $y$ be the two vertices on the left and right; $G-x-y$ will have three components with vertices $a_1, \dots, a_6$, $b_1, \dots, b_6$, and $c_1, \dots, c_6$ respectively.

To define these components, begin by putting down a complete graph on each of them. Then, replace:

1. Edges $a_1a_2$ and $a_3a_4$ by $a_1x, a_2x, a_3y, a_4y$.
2. Edges $b_1b_2$ and $b_3b_4$ by $b_1x, b_2x, b_3y, b_4y$.
3. Edge $c_1c_2$ by $c_1x, c_2y$.

Comment: Great! I have started using `nauty` to search for all 2-connected, 5-regular non-Hamiltonian graphs. It has been running for 18 hours, and I have not obtained any results so far.